# openpyxl merged cells: Formatting issue

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Say I have an xlsx-file and this Excel file has cells A2 and B2 merged. I also select that merged cell and put a border at the top and bottom of the merged cell.

[image: original excel file]

When I do the following:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
wb.save("resulting file.xlsx")
```

The result is that only the portion around the merged cell that is in column *A* now has the border:

[image: resulting excel file]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are facing [Issue#365](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/365/styling-merged-cells-isnt-working) , there is generally an issue around styling for merged cells, I believe the above mentioned issues tracks it.

Sadly, I do not see any workaround for this issue, neither is any such workaround mentioned in the issue linked.

Another issue that is more directly related to the one you are facing (it is closed as duplicate of the above mentioned issue) -

[Issue#378 - Missing border edges on different cells on open and save existing excel file](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/378/missing-border-edges-on-different-cells-on)

Comment: The problem is the lack clarity in the specification. You can only implement properly what's described properly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This is helpful. I've tried some hacks but as you both and the bug report mentioned, it seems like something needs to be done to get passed hacking around the problem.