# Saving an xlsx file with formatted, merged, and locked cells with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl to read in an extensively formatted xlsx file and create a copy with some of the fields populated with specific values. The original file has protection on it (most cells are locked down). Also, many cells are merged together, some horizontally and some vertically. Is there a known issue with saving out such locked/merged/formatted cells? I know that openpyxl does support cell protection, but I'm not clear what the limitations are. All the fields I'm trying to prepopulate are unlocked.

As a test, I loaded the workbook and did nothing more than save it out to the new file, as follows:

```
wb = load_workbook(src_file)
wb.save(out_file)
```

I still lost most of the formatting. It remains in some cells, but others lose all formatting. Additionally, all but one of the cells are incorrectly locked. I'm attaching images of the before and after.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDkSx.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYfC8.png)

I can get the right values into the right cells, but again there is inconsistency in the locked/unlocked state of the cells, on top of the formatting problems.

Does anyone have any insight into ways around this, or have I encountered a limitation of openpyxl?

UPDATE: It seems that the formatting problem is a known issue as stovfl mentions. I looked further at the sheet and the only cell that stayed correctly unlocked as in the input sheet is one that is a single, non-merged cell. So I am going to assume the locking problem is a direct result of the issue with merged cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python openpyxl merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254115/python-openpyxl-merged-cells)

Comment: @stovfl could you reproduce the problem ? there are multiple cases indicated in this question

Comment: @stovfl : as you see here , the openpyxl ,randomly destroys the formatting and formulas, so obviously it might not be reproduceable in the same way in all Excel files. so giving negative vote had no sense